# CKEditor change style of spellchecker scayt

Tags: styles, ckeditor

When SCAYT find a wrong world it will add a style to span with wrong worlds like that :

```
.scayt-enabled [data-scayt_word] {
    background: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBAADAIABAP8NDQAAACH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAEAAMAAAIFRB5mGQUAOw==") repeat-x scroll center bottom transparent !important; 
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important; 
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

But it`s broke my parent style **"word-wrap: break-word"**. How is possible to override this style?

Answer (score 0):

delete `white-space: nowrap` rule, or `!important`, or trie something else and tell us about it. have you tried anything btw?

Comment: Yes, exactly I want to delete this style. But I do not how.:( This style is system, and I can not find where this style is set.